Implementation of Popscope to exit app on pressing back button twice
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';
import 'backend/firebase/firebase_config.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/internationalization.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/nav/nav.dart';
import 'index.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  await initFirebase();

  await FlutterFlowTheme.initialize();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();

  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>()!;

}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale? _locale;
  ThemeMode _themeMode = FlutterFlowTheme.themeMode;

  late AppStateNotifier _appStateNotifier;
  late GoRouter _router;

  bool displaySplashImage = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _appStateNotifier = AppStateNotifier.instance;
    _router = createRouter(_appStateNotifier);

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
        () => setState(() => _appStateNotifier.stopShowingSplashImage()));
  }

  void setLocale(String language) {
    setState(() => _locale = createLocale(language));
  }

  void setThemeMode(ThemeMode mode) => setState(() {
        _themeMode = mode;
        FlutterFlowTheme.saveThemeMode(mode);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Refereevision App',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        FFLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: _locale,
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
      ],
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      themeMode: _themeMode,
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

I need to implement the functionality that the app exits when back button is presses twice.
I am new to flutter programming and am confused where to implement this functionality in the above code.
FYI  Android version 14.
Currently on pressing the back button it just re-navivgates the entire flow in the reverse.
Kindly help.

To implement the functionality where the app exits when the back button is pressed twice, you can use the PopScope widget. This widget allows you to intercept the back button press and perform custom actions. Here's an example of how you can use it:
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_animations.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_icon_button.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_animate/flutter_animate.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:double_tap_to_exit/double_tap_to_exit.dart';

import 'home_page_model.dart';
export 'home_page_model.dart';

 class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePageWidget> createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();
}

class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late HomePageModel _model;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final animationsMap = <String, AnimationInfo>{};
  bool canPop = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => HomePageModel());

    animationsMap.addAll({
      'imageOnPageLoadAnimation': AnimationInfo(
        loop: true,
        trigger: AnimationTrigger.onPageLoad,
        effectsBuilder: () => [
          TiltEffect(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            delay: 1000.0.ms,
            duration: 10000.0.ms,
            begin: Offset(0, 0),
            end: Offset(0, 6.283),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      'circleImageOnPageLoadAnimation': AnimationInfo(
        loop: true,
        reverse: true,
        trigger: AnimationTrigger.onPageLoad,
        effectsBuilder: () => [
          RotateEffect(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            delay: 300.0.ms,
            duration: 10000.0.ms,
            begin: 0.0,
            end: 1.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    });

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: canPop,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        if (!canPop) {
          canPop = true;
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('Press back again to exit'),
            ),
          );

        }
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => _model.unfocusNode.canRequestFocus
              ? FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.unfocusNode)
              : FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Scaffold(
              key: scaffoldKey,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEFDB06),
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                actions: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 1.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'One stop to \"rule\" them all',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyMedium.override(
                            fontFamily: 'North_wave',
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            letterSpacing: 0.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            useGoogleFonts:
                                GoogleFonts.asMap().containsKey('North_wave'),
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}

Also change your home navigation to :-
   context.goNamed('HomePage');


Thanks..... but can you please insert it in my code because i am not sure how to go about adding the popscope widget

Hello Please share the class where you want to implement it i will do it

my expectation is that the app should exit when the user presses the back button on phone.......This is my main.dart file...... My actual homepage is in another file (hompage_widget.dart) I do not know which class to implement it in or in which file to do it

it will be implemented on hompage_widget.dart because that is your main screen where from your ui and routes starts building

I have posted the homepage code.... kindly please insert the popscope functionality

Working as expected...Thanks @arpit for your whole hearted effort

Please accept the answer if it's working well. It would be a big help. @AjoyLawrence

Try this code
DateTime currentBackPressTime;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: WillPopScope(child: getBody(), onWillPop: onWillPop),
  );
}

Future<bool> onWillPop() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null || 
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text("Press back to exit"),
      ));
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }


Check this code
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
          if (_lastPressedAt == null ||
              currentTime.difference(_lastPressedAt!) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
            _lastPressedAt = currentTime;
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text('Press back again to exit'),
              ),
            );
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Title'),
          ),
          body: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


    import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_animations.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_icon_button.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_animate/flutter_animate.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:double_tap_to_exit/double_tap_to_exit.dart';

import 'home_page_model.dart';
export 'home_page_model.dart';

class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePageWidget> createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();

}

class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late HomePageModel _model;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final animationsMap = <String, AnimationInfo>{};



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => HomePageModel());

    animationsMap.addAll({
      'imageOnPageLoadAnimation': AnimationInfo(
        loop: true,
        trigger: AnimationTrigger.onPageLoad,
        effectsBuilder: () => [
          TiltEffect(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            delay: 1000.0.ms,
            duration: 10000.0.ms,
            begin: Offset(0, 0),
            end: Offset(0, 6.283),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      'circleImageOnPageLoadAnimation': AnimationInfo(
        loop: true,
        reverse: true,
        trigger: AnimationTrigger.onPageLoad,
        effectsBuilder: () => [
          RotateEffect(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            delay: 300.0.ms,
            duration: 10000.0.ms,
            begin: 0.0,
            end: 1.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    });

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _model.unfocusNode.canRequestFocus
          ? FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.unfocusNode)
          : FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),

      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEFDB06),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 1.0),
              child: Text(
                'One stop to \"rule\" them all',
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyMedium.override(
                      fontFamily: 'North_wave',
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      letterSpacing: 0.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      useGoogleFonts:
                          GoogleFonts.asMap().containsKey('North_wave'),
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],


@arpit.... please look into this

Hello @Ajoy Edited my answer (check it out )according to your nees please accept if it helps your

@arpit..... i did try ... but application does not exit. please see my code below

So You Want to also exit on first time with message.Because Code I implemented show toast on first time and exit you on second time . If I am Wrong please Discribe Your Use Case

second time... but it does not exit the second time....the pop up shows and then when i press back again it foes not exit.....

What Happens After That ?

It goes to  previous page in the app... and then again when i press the home button... the homepage screen  shows... i press the back button and pop up shows and then when i press back again it moves on to another page which has been navigated to previously

I think you have other screen's in stack but you want to exit app without going to privous screen. again Edited code Likewise used   SystemNavigator.pop(); for this

Still the same issue persists

I can send you the recording of what is happening if you can share your mail id

arpitbabhoria@yopmail.com

Okk Are You using goRouter

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
